# What happen about only using ob_end_flush() without using ob_start() in PHP?

Tags: php, output-buffering

Some code like this:

```
echo 111;
$status = ob_get_status(true);
print_r($status);
/*
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => default output handler [type] => 0 [flags] => 112 [level] => 0 [chunk_size] => 4096 [buffer_size] => 8192 [buffer_used] => 3 ) ) 
*/

var_dump(ob_end_flush()); // true
```

Is it different from using ob_start() first?
What happening about PHP output buffer ?

Comment: [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) - Turn on output buffering, and [ob_end_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) — Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

Comment: Error is: `Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush.`

if you don't start `ob` then nothing is there to end of `ob`.

Comment: @AHJeebon yes,i know.But in my example,i havent use ob_start(),but the result of ob_end_flush() is true.Is "echo" starting output buffering automatically?